# Can you install a dovecot+postfix mail server without ssl certificate?

Tags: postfix, dovecot

Im trying to install a mail server, but am not interested in buying a ssl certificate. Can the mail server be configured without one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but that's absolutely not recommended. Doing so would expose your passwords over a plain text connection for SMTP and IMAP authentication. This is an extremely bad idea (IMHO it borders on criminal negligence).

However, you are lucky as [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates are free to use and there is absolutely no reason not to use them. Furthermore, if you find a reason not to use them anyway, you could even use self-signed certificates, but you have to manually configure your clients to trust those. This might work for small environments and is what I did for my private stuff before Let's Encrypt was available.